# How to control the order of detected objects by regionprops in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on a MATLAB project where the user will upload a scanned image of ellipse-like objects, and the program have to calculate measurements (height, width, area,..etc) of every object in the image.

I started with thresholding that produces a binary image (a black background and white independent objects). This is the BW image after thresholding:

[image: BW image]

After that, I used `regionprops` since it returns most of the measurements that I need, and it worked perfectly.

The problem is that the order in which the function "recognizes/detects" objects is not consistent. I added a code to show the number of each object so I could know which object has `regionprops` considered as the first and which one is the second..etc.

The code:

```
% read image
rgb=imread('bw');

s = regionprops(bw,'Area', 'BoundingBox', 'Eccentricity', 'MajorAxisLength', 'MinorAxisLength', 'Orientation', 'Perimeter','Centroid');


% show the number of each object

imshow(bw)
hold on;

for k = 1:numel(s)
    c = s(k).Centroid;
    text(c(1), c(2), sprintf('%d', k), ...
        'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
        'VerticalAlignment', 'middle', 'color', 'r');
end

hold off;
```

This is the image after showing the order of objects:

[image: BW image with numbered objects]

**I need the order to be from top-left to bottom-right.
( first row of objects is numbered from 1 to 6, 
second row from 7 to 12..etc).
Is that possible?**

Many thanks.

Comment: You can use the `Centroid` of each to order them

Comment: The detection order is as if you convert your matrix to a single column. I.e. go down the rows of the first column and then the second etc. The first 'true' pixel you find is belonging to the first region, and so on.

Comment: @user2999345 But won't that take time??? I mean it is a good thought though .....

Comment: This how the regions are sorted in regionprops output. As @Suever suggested, you can sort them afterwards using their centroids, as obtained from regionprops.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [labeled map](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#inputarg_L), as obtained from bwlabel, as an input to regionprops, the regions order will be the same as their labels. Before applying regionprops set the label indexes according to the desired order.

Comment: @RAO Why have you deleted the code and sample images? Without those, your question is far less comprehensible. It would also be appropriate to accept the answer if it solved your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: @RAO: You may have misunderstood how StackOverflow works.  It is not a service for giving you an answer, it is a service collecting Q&A sets.  Your question and the answers you receive are not solely for your own use, you contributed the question to the site so that it can help others with similar problems in the future.  For that reason, you won't be allowed to rip out the guts and deny future readers the opportunity to learn what you did.

Comment: @Ben
Oooppps I looked so mean I'm sorry.. Actually one of my professors told us about her opinion in getting help from the internet, she was so close-minded she thinks if someone asked even about a very specific point it means she is copying the whole project /= You can notice how I'm interested in knowing more, I asked gnovice to explain more even though the code worked with me by just copying and pasting. So that's why I preferred to remove the images and code, people in real life will misunderstand if they see it.

Comment: @Ben
I replaced with alternative images that will let people understand.
And just removed the preprocessing part of the code which is not related to my question anyway.
Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working off of [Suever's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076798/how-to-control-the-order-of-detected-objects-by-regionprops-in-matlab/43077511#comment73236859_43076798) to use the `Centroid` data, and assuming that `s` contains only the 18 regions of interest in the examples, here's one way to sort `s` from left-to-right, top-to-bottom using [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) and [`sortrows`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
coords = vertcat(s.Centroid);  % 2-by-18 matrix of centroid data
[~, ~, coords(:, 2)] = histcounts(coords(:, 2), 3);  % Bin the "y" data
[~, sortIndex] = sortrows(coords, [2 1]);  % Sort by "y" ascending, then "x" ascending
s = s(sortIndex);  % Apply sort index to s
```

And here's a picture showing the labeling of each area (as you did in your code sample):

[image]

The binning of the "y" data first allows us to group objects into 3 rows of 6. The `sortrows` function, after sorting by this bin value, is then able to do sub-sorting of all the "x" values for each unique binned group.

Comment: Perfect answer (Y)

Comment: Awesome! It worked very well. Thank you so much gnovice. I spent some time reading about "binning" but just got the main concept (I'm new to MATLAB and the whole image processing field). Can you kindly explain the idea of your code more? It will help me a lot. Many thanks.